# Lifetime error using traits and async function on protobuffers

Tags: asynchronous, rust, traits, lifetime, proto

I'm having some issues understanding lifetimes in Rust. It may also be the way I implement my design.

```
error[E0597]: `request` does not live long enough
  --> src/service/session/server.rs:25:23
   |
25 |         let msg_ref = request.get_ref();
   |                       ^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
32 |         let body: Box<dyn Body> = Box::new(signup);
   |                                   ---------------- cast requires that `request` is borrowed for `'static`
...
44 |     }
   |     - `request` dropped here while still borrowed
```

The main source:

```rust
#[tonic::async_trait]
impl Session for SessionImplementation {
    async fn signup(
        &self,
        request: Request<SignupRequest>,
    ) -> Result<Response<SessionResponse>, Status> {
        let msg_ref = request.get_ref();
        let signup = TxSignup::new(&msg_ref.name, &msg_ref.addr, &msg_ref.pwd);

        let body: Box<dyn Body> = Box::new(signup);
        let tx = Transaction::new(body);
        let mut tx_signup: Box<dyn Tx> = Box::new(tx);
        tx_signup.execute();

        let response = SessionResponse {
            deadline: 0,
            cookie: "".to_string(),
            status: 0,
        };

        Ok(Response::new(response))
    }

    /* more code */
}
```

### Background

The idea is to have a `Transaction`, that implements `Tx { execute(&self), result(&self) ... };`. This `Transaction` has a parameter `body` of the type `Box<dyn Box>`, being the trait `Body { /*some fn*/ }`. Having this, I'm pretending to implement some kind of hierarchy.

### The code above

On line 24 I'm getting some requests of the type `SignupRequest` (from proto file). This is the implementation of proto's server, using Tonic and Tokio.
After this, I have also an object `TxSignup` with some parameters of the type `&str` (set in from line 27 till 29). `TxSignup` implements the `Body` trait so I'm able to turn it into a `Tx` trait, apparently. The `Transaction` object wraps a `Body` implementation. I call the `execute()` function from the given trait `Tx`. All that explained has been done from line 32 till 35.

### The problem

If I replace the `&str` type from `TxSignup` by type `String` it works. However, if I want them to be of the type `&str`, a lot of "incongruencies" with lifetimes emerge. I want it to be `&str` because none of these values will change. I think it is better to keep them on the stack instead of in the heap. Am I wrong?

If I want `&str`, I'm coerced to define `TxSignup` with `<'a>`, and here is where I get lost. I get why a lifetime is required, but not why all these problems appear.

As far I do understand, all elements inside the function should have the same lifetime, being killed at the end of its block (line 44). I will never send them outside.

I have tried giving to `Body` trait also an `<'a>`, and even to `Tx` trait (meaning the `Transaction` object must have one too to match the trait).

Is there any way to make it work? Am I misunderstanding the Trait use and how they work, or this patter design will never work?

### Reproduction on GitHub

I have reproduced this same error in my [rust-proto](https://github.com/HectorMRC/rust-proto.git) repository. Running `cargo run` should be enough.

---

I come from Go development and some C++, Java and Python, so I have a way of coding that may not be the most appropriate one using Rust. That's what I want to solve.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: *I think is better to keep them in the stack instead of heap memory. Am I wrong?* — yes, or at least misguided. `&str` / `String` aren't about stack or heap, they are about (lack-of) ownership.

Comment: [To make Stack Overflow a useful resource for future visitors beyond the context of your repository](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380194/155423), please [edit] your question to add a [MRE] in the question itself, in addition to the link to your repository.